# Access appSettings in web.config from Thread in Class Library project

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, httpcontext

Can I able to access `appSettings` section in my ASP.NET web.config file from a method in another referenced Class Library project when it is called as a new `Thread`?
I'm accessing the setting through a property as

```
 private static string TempXmlFolder
 {
      get
      {
           return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReceiptTempPath"] ?? "~/Receipts/TempXML");
      }
 }
```

There is an extension method for the matter to generate the receipt.

```
 internal static void GenerateReceipt(this IMatter matter)
 {
     try
     {
          string XmlFile = TempXmlFolder + "/Rec_" + matter.MatterID + ".xml";
          // ...
          // Generating receipt from the matter contents
          // ...
          // Saving generated receipt
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          ex.WriteLog();
     }
 }
```

I'm calling the receipt generation as a new thread from the class library like

```
 Thread printThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.GenerateReceipt));
 // To avoid exception 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this' (Using WPF controls in receipt generation function)
 printThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 printThread.Start();
 // ...
 // Do another stuffs
 // ...
 // Wait to generate receipt to complete
 printThread.Join();
```

But since the `HttpContext.Current` is null inside the `Thread`, I'm not able to access the current web server configuration file.

Can you suggest there any way other than passing the current `HttpContext` to the `Thread`? If no, what are the things I've to take care to keep thread safety?

### Edit #1

Currently I'm passing the HttpContext to the thread like

```
 System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
 Thread printThread = new Thread(() => this.GenerateReceipt(currentContext));
```

and in the function,

```
 internal static void GenerateReceipt(this IMatter matter, System.Web.HttpContext htCont)
 {
      string TempXmlFolder = htCont.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReceiptTempPath"] ?? "~/Receipts/TempXML");
      //...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `TempXmlFolder` into the thread. Don't rely on `HttpContext.Current`. Alternatively, pass the value of `HttpContext.Current` to the thread and calculate the value of `TempXmlFolder` later.

You can pass the value using any way you want. Maybe a field or a local variable that you capture with a lambda.

Comment: Currently I'm passing the Current `HttpContext` to the `Thread` method. But will there be any problem regarding `thread safety` in passing current `HttpContext` to another `Thread`?